# Paypal Pro Payment Processor problems

Tags: civimember, paypal

We are using Paypal pro to take payments for memberships. We use webforms in Drupal to capture the data into CIVICRM 4.5.8. There are some issues I have outlines in order of importance.

1. We cannot take international payments because the county field does not change when you select a different country. For example West Midlands, Saudi Arabia. Is it possible to get rid of the county field as a required field and hide it? Is the billing address required at all?
2. The page refreshes when something is wrong with the payment information but it does not tell you what is wrong.
3. There is no option to use the users address (shipping address) as the billing address. They have to type it again.

Does anyone know how to fix any of the above. it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These issues has been fixed in the later version 4.6 - If possible please upgrade to version 4.6 that should fix all the issues which you have reported

If you still wanted to fix the issue in the same version - then

Issue 1: you have two solution for the same

you need to hide the existing billingblock country and county field and need to add two new field for the same by overriding CRM/CORE/BillingBlock.tpl

ELSE

In webform_civicrm Module - includes/wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc -> function validateBillingFields() - remove 'billing_state_province_id-5' => FALSE,

Issue 2: I guess this is also related to Version

Issue 3: you need to write a module/condition in drupal to copy over webform address field to the billing address field

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: If you are thinking of upgrading - please create a UAT and test all the function and then go ahead and upgarde your LIVE